# How do you detach connected objects with the Ultrahand?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

I have created a long log bridge with some logs I found. I accidentally attached it to one of the floating platforms and will not break off.

[image]

How do I reclaim my bridge and detach it from the platform?

I noticed things will just break off if you're rough with it but it won't disconnect.

Comment: ... now, if the screen wasn't conveniently cropped and/or the UI overlay disabled, the UI at the bottom would have already shown the required command...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be able to detach things, you need to "shake" it off. If you have motion controls enabled, you can just shake your controller while holding onto the part you want. With it disabled, you can just move your right stick in an up/down motion or right left motion (or anything that feels like wiggling it all around,) until it disconnects. As far as I can tell, there's no dedicated button to disconnect them.

Comment: "shake it off” - Great. Now every time I play Tears of the Kingdom, I’ll think about the Taylor Swift song

Comment: Note that only things connected by Ultrahand can be detached. This applies to stuff you find that is already attached with the green stuff. Anything that is connected without that green stuff can't be detached using Ultrahand.